# What are QKeyEvent.nativeModifiers()?

Tags: qt, cross-platform, keyboard-events, modifier-key, pyside6

What are QKeyEvent.nativeModifiers()? The documentation doesn't say much (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QKeyEvent.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QKeyEvent.nativeModifiers). From what I understand, the integer that is returned by calling this method on a QKeyEvent object represents the full state of the modifier keys (Ctrl, Shift, Alt, etc.).

Moreover, I would assume that the mapping between these integers and their respective modifier states is systematic, so is there a way to test whether a given modifier state contains a specific modifier (e.g. by using the "&" operator)?

Importantly, are the native modifiers cross-platform such that a Left Ctrl keypress on a PC returns the same integer as a Left Command on a Mac (since Qt.Key_Control corresponds to the MacOS command keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As name suggests native modifiers has different values on mac and on pc. On windows value is a combination of [WindowsNativeModifiers](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowskeymapper.h?h=6.1.0#n117), on macOS it is a combination of [NSEventModifierFlags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventmodifierflags/), both translated to `Qt::KeyboardModifiers` ([windows](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowskeymapper.cpp?h=6.1.0#n944) [macOS](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qnsview_keys.mm?h=6.1.0#n48)) which is same on both platforms.